# Why do the rotating brushes on my Hoover vacuum only work when it's in the upright position?

Tags: repair, cleaning

I have the blue Hoover pet cyclonic vacuum.  It worked fine for a few months, but now when I push the foot lever to lower the handle when I vacuum, the brushes stop spinning on any carpet level setting.  Once the vacuum is locked into an upright position, they spin perfectly.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Start by consulting the owners manual for how to check/tighten belts.

Comment: I only work in the upright position, once i am reclined i am no longer inclined to work. Work sucks like hoover.

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure this is a bug, and not a feature

When the vacuum is in the upright position, the agitator should not rotate.  When the handle is lowered the agitator should be engaged, however, some models offer a manual agitator shut off feature.  Make sure if your model has this feature, it is not turned on.

> [image: Agitator Brushroll Shut Off]

## Check the hose

Next ensure that when you lower the handle, the attachment hose is not becoming dislodged.  On some vacuums if the hose is removed, the lower portion of the vacuum disengages.

## Check the belts

If one of the belts becomes worn or stretched, the agitator may spin fine until it comes under load. Once the agitator meets resistance, the belt slips, and the agitator stops spinning. Consult the user manual on how to check and replace belts in your particular model.

> [image: Belt]
> [image: V Belt]

Image source: [Pet Cyclonic Bagless Upright](http://hoover.com/products/details/uh70085/pet-cyclonic-bagless-upright/) [Owners Manual](http://hoover.com/file/561/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its a belt or hose, if it rotates at all your belt is fine. The problem is most likely the switch inside where the brush head connects to the body. When you move your vac from the upright position its supposed to click the brush head on. This is most likely broken.